# Windows x64 stack walking

Tags: c++, windows, stack, stack-trace

I'm trying to walk the stack of another process but sadly StackWalk64 doesn't seem to be working for some functions.  As an example the below call stack for calling 'getchar' looks like this in my debugger:

```
000000007388e492()  Unknown
avcuf64.dll!00000000728da2f2()  Unknown
avcuf64.dll!000000007288bd94()  Unknown
0000000073880872()  Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007ffb604083a8()   Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb40261188()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb4026052c()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb4017348e()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb401711f9()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb4017123d()    Unknown
msvcr120d.dll!00007ffb40171259()    Unknown  (This is getchar)
Performance.exe!main() Line 54  C++
Performance.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 626    C
Performance.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 466   C
kernel32.dll!00007ffb62db13d2() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffb631a03c4()    Unknown
```

However StackWalk64 fails at the 0000000073880872 function because I don't have a valid debugHlp because this piece of code does not reside inside a loaded module.  I think this is to do with my antivirus software 'avcuf64.dll' generating code.

So anyway I decided to try and do this manually but the standard way of stack walking manually using RtlLookupFunctionEntry and RtlVirtualUnwind doesnt appear to be valid for working on threads in different processes.  Does anybody know if this is true and if so what you can do instead to get at the unwind metadata for a different process?

Here's what it looks like on a different Win7 machine (above was Win8.1) with no keylogger protection and symbols resolved (once I get the chance I'll resolve the above with symbols):

```
ntdll.dll!ZwRequestWaitReplyPort()  Unknown
kernel32.dll!ConsoleClientCallServer()  Unknown
kernel32.dll!ReadConsoleInternal()  Unknown
kernel32.dll!ReadConsoleA() Unknown
kernel32.dll!TlsGetValue()  Unknown
msvcr110d.dll!_read_nolock(int fh, void * inputbuf, unsigned int cnt) Line 251  C
msvcr110d.dll!_read(int fh, void * buf, unsigned int cnt) Line 92   C
msvcr110d.dll!_filbuf(_iobuf * str) Line 136    C
msvcr110d.dll!getc(_iobuf * stream) Line 75 C
msvcr110d.dll!_fgetchar() Line 38   C
msvcr110d.dll!getchar() Line 47 C
Test.exe!main() Line 7  C++
Test.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536   C
Test.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377  C
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

Comment: what does it look like when you turn off the antivirus?

Comment: Added to main question